# Force Port in Foreman changes from 3000 to 3100

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I have a .foreman file with the following line:

```
port: 3000
```

Then in my Procfile.dev I have the following:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

However, when running the server by doing:

`foreman -f Procfile.dev`, Ig get the following:

Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3100`

Why is that happening? Why is not starting at 3000, but at the 3100?

After digging a little bit further, I realized that in my Procfile, I have the first line as:

```
redis: redis-server
```

When moving that to the second line, and placing the:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

As my first line, it works fine.  Why would that order matter at all?

Comment: What server are you running? thin, puma, unicorn? It's possible you have a configuration file for that server that is overriding the command line.

Comment: I am running the default server that comes with Rails. It says 'Booting WEBrick'

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804184/why-is-foreman-gem-ignoring-the-port-environment-variable

Comment: Could it be the order of the commands in the Procfile? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28341280/59991